# Why is terraform ignoring my terragrunt inputs?

Tags: input, module, terraform, terraform-provider-aws, terragrunt

Recently I took over a terraform & terragrunt project a previous person worked on, and unfortunately I can not get it to work properly, meaning that the terragrunt inputs are totally ignored by terraform.

```
TERRAFORM_VERSION: 1.2.8
TERRAGRUNT_VERSION: 0.38.8
```

Here is the folder structure:

```
tf
├── terraform
│   └── aws
│       ├── modules
│       │   └── testapp
│       │       ├── main.tf
│       │       ├── outputs.tf
│       │       └── provider.tf
│       └── resources
│           └── testapp
│               ├── main.tf
│               └── variables.tf
└── terragrunt
    ├── env
    │   └── test
    │       ├── env.yaml
    │       └── testapp
    │           └── terragrunt.hcl
    └── terragrunt.hcl
```

Content of files:

**terragrunt testapp terragrunt.hcl:**

```
terraform {
  source = "/tf/terraform/aws//modules/testapp"
}

include "root" {
  path = find_in_parent_folders()
}

locals {
  env = yamldecode(file(find_in_parent_folders("env.yaml")))
}

inputs = {
  name = "whatever-test"
}
```

**modules testapp main.tf:**

```
module "test" {
  source = "/tf/terraform/aws/resources/testapp"
}
```

**resources testapp main.tf:**

```
resource "aws_iam_policy" "test_policy" {
  name   = "test-${var.name}-policy"
  ...etc...
}
```

**resources testapp variables.tf:**

```
variable "name" {
  type = string
}
```

When running the apply command, I get the following error, and cant figure out why the variable is ignored:

```bash
terragrunt apply --terragrunt-source-update --terragrunt-config /tf/terragrunt/env/test/testapp/terragrunt.hcl


│ Error: Missing required argument
│
│   on main.tf line 1, in module "test":
│    1: module "test" {
│
│ The argument "name" is required, but no definition was found.
╵
ERRO[0030] Terraform invocation failed in /tf/.terragrunt-cache/EsgHHSh0qo-NO_uijOaMYnlcMZI/bmBahUj5mD_HVKsk-dPyhY4f1cA/modules/testapp  prefix=[terragrunt/env/test/testapp]
ERRO[0030] 1 error occurred:
        * exit status 1
```

I dont get why terragrunt source points towards a module file, instead of pointing to the resources, but unfortunately the whole project is done this way, and refactoring it would take a long time and its not on the priority list right now. In this case, what can I do to make terraform see my inputs from terragrunt?

Here is also the content of some of the other files:

**terragrunt test env.yaml:**

```
environment: "test-env"
region: "eu-west-1"
```

**terragrunt root terragrunt.hcl:**

```
remote_state {
  backend = "s3"

  config = {
    encrypt                      = true
    region                       = "eu-west-1"
    key                          = "${path_relative_to_include()}/terraform.tfstate"
    bucket                       = "tf-state"
    dynamodb_table               = "test-table"
    skip_bucket_accesslogging    = true
    disable_aws_client_checksums = true
    s3_bucket_tags = {
      name = "test"
    }
  }
}
```

A help would be really appreciated with this. Thank you!

Comment: The module requires you to assign an input variable called `name` a value when calling the module. Since you are not doing that terraform is letting you know what to do.

Comment: @MarkoE I tried that before posting the question, and unfortunately it does not work either. I created a variables.tf file with the variable "name" defined, similar to the one in the variable file present in the resources folder.

Comment: @MarkoE New update: Apparently besides adding the variable in the module, I also had to define "name = var.name" inside the module block. Its weird as this way i create redundant variable files, in modules and resources, and also inside the module block. Would  there be any proper alternative to do this?